# Beier Neely Morphing (Visual Computing)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm currently working on an assignment for school and I'm a bit stuck. The resources I've look at are in this [tutorial](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hasinoff/320/pyramid-morphing.txt) (second half of page) and the algorithm I've tried to code is in this [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/papers/beier92.pdf). For reasons of (my class assignments get recycled) I can't post my code on here, so I'll do a breakdown of what I'm understanding and hopefully someone can point out a problem with my understanding. If not that, then 1-1 help looking at my (carefully commented) C++ would be appreciated, if at all possible.

I'm given a VXL image that can be accessed via the RBG pixel values for a source, and a destination, and I'm also given a structure that contains lines (referred to by their start and end point coordinates), additionally variable a, b, and p are given.

So I go through the destination image coordinates (double loop through i, j), and then an inner loop through the lines. I calculate u and v as follows:

- `u = dot_product(XP,QP) / || QP * QP ||`

where XP is the coordinate of the destination *X(i,j) - P(i,j)*, the starting point of the line
and QP is *Q(i,j) - P(i,j)* where Q is the end point of the line, and || denotes magnitude

- `v = dot_product(perpQP, XP) / || QP ||`

where perpQP = QP(-i, j)

Then using P'Q' the lines from the source, I calculate X'

- `X' = P' + u * Q'P' + ( v*perpQ'P'/ || QP || )`

where X' are the coordinates from the source image and *X' in [0, length/width of image]* (restricted by dimensions of image, and pixels accessible)

- `weight = ( (|| QP ||)^p / (a + dist) )^b`

where dist is given by *( abs(v) if u in (0,1) ) or ( ||XQ|| if u > 1 ) or ( ||XP|| if u < 0)*

so I've tried implementing it in 2 ways which end up giving the same thing, so they must be equivalent, as is in the paper where X_ for each destination pixel is set to `**X_ = X + DSUM/ weightsum**` so that `**DSUM += D * weight**` and `**D = X' - X**` and `**weightsum += weight**` (these are calculated in the inner loop), and X_ is calculated for every destination coordinate

and I've tried to implement it as the tutorial does so that `**X_ = DSUM/weightsum**` where `**DSUM = X' * weight**` and weightsum is the same as the previous

This assignment is due April 3, and yes this is considered having started early when in university. First time asking a question on these boards, hopefully someone can be a bit helpful in a non esoteric way with tons of over my head explanations. I have enough of that in class with my professors insulting my intelligence in class.

Comment: I'm a little suspect about `v = dot_product(perpQP, XP) / || XP ||` this seems to be the wrong scalling. I would have expected `v = dot_product(perpQP, XP) / || QP * QP ||` as this has a similar denominator to the `u` expression. In the paper the denominator is `||QP||`.

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo! I meant QP, I did try your suggestion and squared it but it didn't give quite the correct output either. Thank you though!

Comment: Yes if you look in the paper they did actually try squaring and found the results we not that good.

Comment: Have you tried it with just a single line. It should product a simple affine transformation. Do you have the actual code your using?

Comment: I sent you an e-mail to the one I found on your website with the code. I hope that's okay.